# Can I sort one table by information contained in an unassociated other table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sorting, activerecord

Rails 5.1.6
Ruby 2.5.1

So, I have three models:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :order_items, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :product_type
end

class ProductType < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
end

class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
end
```

I need the ability to sort all of the order items by product type. Alphabetically by the Name of the product type which is only held in the product type table. The product tabled contains the product_type_id. Right now I am sorting by the product_type_id, but that is not alphabetical obviously. I'm trying to understand how I can sort the order_items by information contained in an unrelated table. Perhaps this is not possible? How can I make this possible?

```
scope :sort_by_product_info, -> {(
  select("order_items.id, order_items.order_id, order_items.product_id, 
  order_items.quantity, products.id, products.name, 
  products.description, products.image, products.size, 
  products.product_type_id")
   .joins(:product)
   .order("products.product_type_id ASC, products.name ASC")
)}
```

My thought is that this can't be done through ActiveRecord, which I was hoping, but instead must use raw SQL here.

```
@products_w_type = <<-SQL
  SELECT * 
  FROM order_items, products, product_types 
  JOIN products 
  ON order_items.product_id = products.id 
  JOIN product_types 
  ON products.product_type_id = product_types.id;
SQL
```

the above gives me nil, but it's my first time trying to insert SQL into rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following scope should help you get it sorted the way you wanted:

```
class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product

  scope :sort_by_product_info, -> { joins(product: :product_type).
                                    order('product_types.name ASC, products.name ASC') }
end
```

Also a neat trick you can use to inspect the underlying SQL query is by using the `.explain` method in console:

```
OrderItem.sort_by_product_info.explain
```

Comment: Whoa. Thank you! yes! That works perfectly. Do you have any resources on how to build that kind of query? Or what it is referenced as? I've been googling all over. Also, that explain method is amazing!! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped. You can always check out https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html and play around with the query in console. Remember to upvote my answer if it is what you're looking for. Thanks.